# My DevExpress GridControl scrollbar won't scroll?

Tags: winforms, devexpress

I have a DevExpress GridControl on a WinForms app that has a lot of columns in it.  My horizontal scrollbar is shown on the GridControl.  But, when I expand one of my columns, instead of scrolling horizontally, it just shrinks another column in the same GridControl!  It's nutty!  Does anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you have fixed the size of the grid control than when you expand any column it'll take place form the next column and that will get shrink. Use min Width property also for column width that will fix the minimum size of the column.